# How know date when expire and create date for cache file in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I'm using Ruby3+ and Rails 6+ and cache file : `config.cache_store = :file_store, 'public/cache'`

I try :

```rb
key = 'test'
Rails.cache.write(key, 'test!!')
```

cache files works fine :

```
Rails.cache.read(key)
=> "test!!"
```

but if I try the solution found on other post on SO like this :

```
Rails.cache.send(:read_entry, key, {}).expires_at
```

I have the following error :

```
/home/USER/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:131:in `read_entry': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
```

If I try remove the last arg `{}`,  there is no error, but return nil ...

So how can I find expiration and creation date of my cache?

Comment: @razvans I want show on page the date of cache creation (for know date of information) ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround you could use if you want to know when a cached item was created.

You could write the creation date along with your data

```rb
key = "some key"
Rails.cache.write(key, { expires_at: Time.current + 1.day, value: "test!!!" })`
```

Then retrieve it with

```rb
item = Rails.cache.read(key)
item[:value] 
# => test!!!

item[:expires_at]
# => 20211023********
```

You could easily turn this into some utility helper methods to make your life easier.

```rb
# In some helper or utility class

def write_to_cache(key, value, expiry_time = 1.day)
  Rails.cache.write(key, { expires_at: Time.current + expiry_time, value: value })
end

def cache_key_value(key)
  item = Rails.cache.read("key")
  item[:value]
end

def cache_key_expires_at(key)
  item = Rails.cache.read("key")
  item[:expires_at]
end

# somewhere else
key = "test"
write_to_cache(key, "test value")

cache_key_value(key)
# => "test value"

cache_key_expires_at(key)
# => 20211023********
```

Comment: that works but it's a cheat, I want same without cache the date itself, just use the date of file cache it's enougth...

Comment: It's not a cheat in any way, it is a workaround, what programming is about a lot of times. It also works for all cache types, redis, memcache...